# Upgrade ticket booked via trainline.com and then refund it

Tags: uk, trains, france, refunds, trainline

I booked a non-refundable train ticket from London to Paris (return journey) via [Trainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/) just today. Unfortunately later that same day I put my passport through the washing machine, completely obliterating it.

I see on Trainline that while I can't refund the ticket, I can change the dates. Interestingly as part of this, I can upgrade the ticket to business class, which it says is fully refundable.

While clearly not intended on their end, is this method of getting a refund possible?

Comment: I don't know the answer. From this retired attorney's perspective, the T&C may specify that refunds be issued by trainline.com only on purchased tickets, and not on upgraded ones.

Comment: Eurostar says "We are unable to offer upgrades to Business Premier." If this is still true, the process probably fails at a later step.

Comment: Interested to know if you tried this and whether it worked. I guess not because either it failed due to the reason @Anders gave or it would be an expensive way to find out it didn't.

Comment: I didn't try it yeah, since the risks seem sort of high.